# Using Xcode storyboard causes Xcode to freeze, and Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool spikes to %99

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode-storyboard

I'm using Xcode 6.0.1 to develop an iOS 8 app and I'm getting a new error that I never got when I was using Xcode 5 and iOS 7: when I use the story board builder, Xcode often freezes up with the spinning beach ball of doom (or whatever they call it). Sometimes, all it takes is moving an object in a view controller to cause this.

I have noticed that, when this error happens, my Activity Monitor shows that the "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" process has a % CPU value of between 98 and 100! I have to force quit this process and force close Xcode (which is unresponsive). However, this doesn't solve the problem, because it comes back when I use the story board again later, and sometimes it comes back when I simply try to open Xcode.

I have also tried restarting my computer and clearing out the derived data, neither of which have solved the problem. I also turned indexing off so that Xcode wouldn't index all my files and run really slowly. This didn't help though.

I've seen other people with this same problem (using older versions of Xcode), but none of them have provided a solution that worked for me.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this bug too,

It seems it has been fixed with xcode 6.1 (download it in apple developer member center).

Comment: Thanks! I'm updating now.

Comment: I can now use the storyboard in Xcode 6.1 without fear of freezing Xcode! Thanks.

Comment: However, with Xcode 6.1, I'm getting a new error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478246/text-views-and-image-view-disappearing-from-view-controller-in-xcode-6-1-storybo

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Xcode 6.0.1. We have been able to get around it by opening text files between any files that use the interface builder.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "opening text files between any files that use the interface builder". Could you please explain it further? Thanks!

Comment: The bug seems to occur when you have a file open in the interface builder, and then open a new file that also utilizes the interface builder. If you first open a plain text file i.e. a swift, or obj-c file, and then move to the new file that uses the interface designer you should not run into this bug.

Comment: So, does an Objective-C file that has outlets count as a file that uses the interface builder?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and was stuck for hours today and I really hate Apple for their incompetence.
In my case the iPad storyboard was still working fine but the iPhone storyboard was broken and resulted in freezing XCode

This is how I solved the problem:

1. Download XCode 5.1.1 again and install it (Just put the .app file somewhere else than in Applications)
2. Open your project in the old version and open the Storyboard
3. Resolve all warnings in the Storyboard (the red and yellow icons in the storyboard) by clicking "fix" on all issues
4. Save the storyboard
5. Reopen in Xcode 6

Best
Robert

Comment: That did it for me. Xcode 5.1 offered to upgrade the Xcode 4 storyboard. After which I was able to open in Xcode 6.1 without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in Xcode 6.1 when opening a storyboard with the "View As" property in the File Inspector set to "iOS 6.1 and Earlier". The document was set to open in Xcode 4.6, which is no longer supported in Xcode 6.1. Upgrading the doc version to Xcode 5.1 or later fixed it.

If you are having difficulty upgrading the version, try to open the storyboard in an earlier version of Xcode (6.0.1 worked for me), and open the File Inspector tab in the storyboard.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue in XCode 6.1. But I modified all storyboard files in my project by editing text file, find useAutolayout, and set its value to NO. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue in Xcode 6.2 (6C131e). I opened the project in an earlier Xcode version (5.1.1 (5B1008). Quit Xcode and reopen the project again in Xcode 6.2 fixed the problem.