# Xcode 6.1 6A1052d Text View disappear after expand label or button size

Tags: xcode6.1

1. Drag label or button into storyboard
2. Drag Text View to storyboard.
3. Try to expand width or height for label or button with mouse drag the corners, the Text View will disappear in Storyboard view controller.

[image: Before expand label size]

[image: After expand label size and Text View missing]

Comment: Looks like Xcode 6.1 bug - lol. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478246/text-views-and-image-view-disappearing-from-view-controller-in-xcode-6-1-storybo