# XCode 6.1 UIImageView disappears

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiimageview, xcode6.1

Related question: [Text views and image view disappearing from view controller in Xcode 6.1 storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478246/text-views-and-image-view-disappearing-from-view-controller-in-xcode-6-1-storybo)

That started happening after the latest update to XCode 6.1 a couple of days ago. I've got a very primitive layout:

[image]

If I open the storyboard source code and then switch back to the Interface Builder mode, then all UIImageView dimensions become zeros.

[image]

Not depending on whether I can see the UIImageView in the storyboard, it won't appear in the running app. The storyboard and the app worked fine prior to the update to XCode Version 6.1 (6A1052d)

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.myImage.sizeToFit()
    let img : UIImage = UIImage(data: imgData.value)!
    self.myImage.image = img
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out XCode 6.1 imposes more strict constraints on the storyboard layout (*not sure whether it is a bug or a feature*).

Here are the steps which worked for me.

Storyboard view

[image]

Constraints

[image]

UIImageView content mode

[image]

Prior to XCode 6.1 I didn't have any specific constraints on the UIImageView. With XCode 6.1 it looks like the constraints are not optional any more.