# Xcode 6.1: UIViews disappearing in interface builder when adjusting frames

Tags: uiview, interface-builder, xcode6

I'm fairly new to Interface Builder and I'm trying to practice it with a very simple `view`. Basically, I have 3 `UIViews` on my `view controller`. The problem I am having is that whenever I adjust the frame of 1 of the UIViews, the other 2 will disappear.

Here is a short 7 second video of the problem: https://vine.co/v/OMlbMIdWMe5

If I run the app on my device, I only see 1 of the views (the 1 I was adjusting) - the other 2 remain hidden.

I am using `Xcode 6.1` . What could be causing this?

***EDIT: If I add 1 constraint to a view, it won't disappear when I readjust the frame of the other view. That is:

Add a constraint to `ViewOne` then readjusting size of `ViewTwo` will only cause `ViewThree` (without any constraints) to disappear.

So the solution is to add constraints to all 3 views before readjusting the frame of any of them. But still, what could be causing this issue?

Comment: I ran into the same issue today...no answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue with Xcode 6.1, and has been reported to apple. A similar post can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478246/text-views-and-image-view-disappearing-from-view-controller-in-xcode-6-1-storybo)

WORKAROUND: I have found that you can edit the constraints in the right hand pane of the storyboard editor, in the size inspector. It actually does not prove that tedious.

Comment: Yeah, you just need to add at least 1 constraint to each view to prevent it from disappearing

Answer (score -1):

You can disable autolayout if you don't need it, that helps.
Otherwise, wait for next patch~