# Can not see TableView in main.storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, tableview, xcode-storyboard

So I know there is a `UITableView`, but it does not show up in the `UIStoryboard` and neither does it in the simulator. Maybe it has something to do with the relative positioning? because when I descaled the `UITextfield` it disappeared. Here is a screenshot:

[image: the simulator]

Of course I can delete the referencing outlets and add the `UITableView` again, but that would cause a situation in which there are two table views.

**Update: FIXED**

I fixed this issue by showing the **Document Outline**, accessible by clicking the [image: icon] icon (the menu in the left of the window). By selecting the `UITableView`, it appeared that the `UITableView` was a `1px` by `1px` area under the `UITextfield`. I simply resized the `UITableView` and dragged it to the center of the screen.

Comment: Please add some details about your views hierarchy

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26838054/3606887)

Comment: select your storyboard and uncheck the "Use Auto Layout" now select your table object in list of elements in your view. It must be in upper right or left corner of the simulator. drag it to orgnal position.... thats it. :)

Comment: @Zubair This does not work :( I can still not see them in the corners or whereever. I looked in the plain text version of the main.storyboard but it says nothing about positioning. I also tried to clear all constraints, but that did not work as well.

Comment: Go to the 'document outline' and select the table view.  Check the 'Size Inspector' properties.  Is the table view's frame in the visible portion of the parent view?