# Pass parameter when initialising UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I have this UICollectionViewCell subclass and I am trying to pass a value to the cell when I initialise it.

```
class AddItemCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var addItemButton = UIButton()
    var collectionElement  : PFObject?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addItemButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
        addItemButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 170, 300)
        addItemButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        addItemButton.addTarget(self, action: "addItemToCollectionElement:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        addItemButton.setTitle("New Item", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        addItemButton.titleLabel!.font =  UIFont(name: "Cochin-BoldItalic", size: 20)
        self.addSubview(addItemButton)
    }

    init (frame: CGRect, passedCollectionElement : PFObject){
        self.collectionElement = passedCollectionElement
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    func addItemToCollectionElement (sender : UIButton!) {

    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Clearly the method being called is the overridden one. Is there a way to call the second / any other way to pass the variable value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to initialize your object with some extra parameters and make the overridden init get called as well you'll need to use convenience initializer as follow:

```
convenience init (frame: CGRect, passedCollectionElement : PFObject){
    self.init(frame: frame)
    self.collectionElement = passedCollectionElement
}
```

This way by calling `let cell = AddItemCell(frame:someFrame, passedCollectionElement : someElement)` will initialize your object by calling both the convenience and designated initializers. You can learn more about initialization [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html)

Comment: The code creates an error at self.init(frame: frame). It says "Missing argument for parameter passedCollectionElement in call"

Comment: If I do self.init(frame: frame, passedCollectionElement : passedCollectionElement), then the first line causes an error: "use of self in delegate initialiser before self.init is called"

Comment: Edited my answer: self.init(frame:frame) should be call before setting collection element

Comment: How should let  cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ItemCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ItemCell be modified?

Comment: If you are using `dequeueReusableCell` you can set collection item directly by using `cell. collectionElement  = someElement` and you don't need initializer at all

Comment: Oh, ok. I wasn't doing that because it seems that if I do that the value is set after the execution of the method override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

Comment: I think you should programmatically add cell to collection view and not by using storyboard. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27107329/1422333 to see how to do that